# How to find out Error No. in ObjFPC in a try-except statement

Tags: pascal, freepascal, delphi

I am trying to find a way to detect the error no in objfpc, what I tried is shown below:

```
Program ErrorHandling;
{$R+}
{$MODE objfpc}

Uses
SysUtils, crt;

Var
  intvar: 1 .. 100;

Begin
  Try
   clrscr;
    writeln( 'enter intvar: ');
    readln(intvar);


  Except
    on
    e: Exception
       Do
       Begin
         writeln('In Exception, IOResult: ',IOResult);
         Case IOResult Of
           201: writeln('Range intvar out of range 1-100!'); {How can we find that Error no is 201}
           Else
             writeln('Unkown Error!'); readln;
         End

       End



End;

writeln('intvar: ' , intvar);
readln;
End.
```

But How can we find if the 201 Range Error occurs. I tried using IOResult command but it always shows "Unknown Error" string of my case statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using exceptions you can check error type by type of exception itself.

The classic way is:

```
try
    clrscr;
    writeln('enter intvar: ');
    readln(intvar);
except
    on e: ERangeError do // Executes when raised exception is ERangeError
    begin
        Writeln('Range intvar out of range 1-100!');
    end;
    on e: Exception do // Executes for any other exceptions
    begin
        Writeln(e.ClassName); // Shows exception class you can use at the "on e:" constuction
        Writeln(e.Message);
    end;
end;
```

Look at [The try...except statement](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse102.html#x213-22300017.2) in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks Abelisto. I was going through fpc official docs but there is nothing about ERangeError, although some math exceptions are given there, can you direct me to a list of all exceptions present in SysUtils.Exceptions

Comment: @user3051677 [http://freepascal.org/docs.var](http://freepascal.org/docs.var) -> [Run-Time Library (RTL) units reference manual](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/index.html) -> [sysutils](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/index.html) -> [Classes](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/index-4.html), then look at classes started with `E`.